# Unable to open file on server

Tags: php, file

`Warning: fopen(..\articles\Bs37NLAXiPOWBKZwy5XByIAMAO25ln05.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/******/public_html/abcd/index.php on line 19 Unable to open file!`

getting this error while opening txt file on server

Comment: The error pretty much says it all: `No such file or directory`. The file you want to open does not exist. Also, your slashes look off, you're using backslashes (Windows style), but your server seems to have a filesystem with forward slashes (Unix style).

Comment: thanx got solution

Answer (score 0):

The file does not exists.

Check the path and filename and make sure it´s existing and accessable for the user which is executing the script.

Share your folder structure in order to help you any further.

Comment: folder has access to all user

Comment: thanx got solution

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is trying to use a windows path "..\articles\Bs37NLAXiPOWBKZwy5XByIAMAO25ln05.txt" not a unix path, as indicated by your error.

Comment: `../articles/Bs37NLAXiPOWBKZwy5XByIAMAO25ln05.txt` as already postet above

Comment: That wasnt there when I loaded the screen.. doesnt make it any less of an answer

Comment: thanx got solution

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file exists before opening it:

```
if (file_exists($path)) {
    fopen($path);
} else {
    echo "File is not exists";
}
```

Comment: There has to be  existance on file.....thats why i am not checking existance of file

Comment: You havent shown any code - the fact its saying it cant open it, either then the file exists or you dont have permission

Comment: i haven't set any permission on host server

Comment: thanx got solution

Comment: sorry for bad english...wkwkwk